# How to compare all of the elements in an array using assert_equal in MiniTest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am comparing the values in the array, but when the condition fails, it exits. Here I wanted to compare all the elements of the array irrespective of pass and fail:

```
val.each do | x |
    #assert_equal 48000.00, x
    assert(48000.00 == x, message = " :Pass")
end
```

Suppose the array size is 20. It should iterate 20 times irrespective of pass or fail condition and should raise the assertion.

Comment: Why dont you use `assert_equal(val, ['val1', 'val2']`? Or if only 48000.00 should be in the array `assert_equal(val.uniq, [48000.00])`? (In your example each value in the array should be 48000.00)

Comment: Why would you want to keep going if a test fail?, maybe you can test in the different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer your question:

The question sounds 'wrong', Why would you want to keep going if a test fail? 
I have the impression, there is a deeper misunderstanding of the test logic. Maybe you can provide more informations to see, what problem you have behind this question.

Here's a full MWE for your question:

```
class TestArray < MiniTest::Test
  VAL = [
    48000.0,
    48000.0,
    3,
    48000.0,
  ]

  def test_orig
    VAL.each do | x |
      assert(48000.00 == x, message = " :Pass")
    end
  end
```

This tests if all entries in the array are 48000.0. You can make similar tests with:

```
    def test_array #expects exact 4 entries.
      assert_equal([48000.00,48000.00,48000.00,48000.00], VAL, message = " :Pass")
    end
    def test_array_2 #flexible number of entries
      assert_equal([48000.00] * VAL.size, VAL, message = " :Pass")
    end
    def test_array_uniq
      assert_equal([48000.00], VAL.uniq, message = " :Pass")
    end
```

With

```
    def test_diff
      assert_equal([], VAL - [48000.0], 'Entries not 48000.0 found')
    end
```

you would get all entries not equal 48000.0.

But there is still the question:
Why would you want to keep going if a test fail?

Tests stop after the first fail. So the only possibility is a test for each value in its own test routine:

```
  class TestArray < MiniTest::Test
    VAL = [
      48000.0,
      48000.0,
      3,
      48000.0,
    ]
    VAL.each_with_index do |val,i|
      define_method :"test_single_value_#{i+1}" do
        assert(48000.00 == val, message = "Diff for entry %i" % [i+1])
      end
    end
  end
```

The code generates a test for each entry in the array. But to get this test possibility, `VAL` must be known before the tests are running. So probably this will not fit your need.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.! It helped alot to resolved my issue. "define_method" worked well with my existing framework and now i am able to achive my expected result.     --Thank you